# Setting AssemblyCopyright, AssemblyCompany in AssemblyInfo during build

Tags: powershell, tfs, build-process, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

We are migrating to a new TFS 2015 server from TFS 2010. I have most everything working, however I haven't found an easy way to set information in the AssemblyInfo.cs file like was being done in 2010.

We need to force the AssemblyCompany, AssemblyCopyright, AssemblyVersion, and AssemblyFileVersion attributes so we don't have to rely on individual developers to get them right. While a shared AssemblyInfo file would work, it would require manually adding it to each project, which still puts the responsibility in the hands of the developer creating the assembly. Not ideal.

Our 2010 xaml build definition had a "Build Versioning" section where these values could be set as shown below.

[image]

I can find no such thing in the vNext build definitions. I am suspecting that perhaps there was some sort of addin which gave this capability on the old system. Unfortunately I didn't set that system up, and the person who did no longer works here, so I don't know for sure and have no idea how he did it if it was an addin.

I've found some PowerShell scripts which will allow setting the version numbers, but so far I haven't come across any that do AssemblyCompany or AssemblyCopyright.

Before I spend the time to write something from scratch, does anyone else know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Googling resulted in [this](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs-automatically-versioning-assemblies-as-part-of-the-build/) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/882584/Continuous-Delivery-with-TFS-Automatically-Version). Chances are you've seen this, but I'm mentioning this in case you did not.

Comment: Yes, those links look like what the old xaml build definition was probably running, but I don't believe they are supported for the new (vNext?) build definitions. I could probably figure out how to make it work with the old xaml templates on the new server (the are still supported for now), but I'd rather not waste my time on a technology that MS is intending to phase out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are looking to increase the assembly version on each build. In vNext build to do that you need to follow the below:

1. Get the ApplyVersionToAssemblies.ps1 script from the Use a script to customize your build process [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/index) documentation and save it to your work space.
2. Add this to source control.
3. Create a new build.
4. Add a build step to call this new script

   A. Press the Add Build Step… button/link
   B. Select the PowerShell build step and move it up so that it is the first task to be executed.
   C. Enter the source control path to your new script
   [REFER HERE](http://incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/)

Comment: Saw that, but that link provides a solution for the version number only, not the company or copyright which is what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The options that you had in TFS2010 XAML build definition were due to the fact that build template was customized.

In TFS2015 vNext build templates you have to add your own build step(most probably a PowerShell script) that'll recreate your logic regarding the AssemblyInfo processing.

Comment: Yes, I had already gathered that. I was hoping maybe someone already had a script that does all the assembly properties and not just the version, but it doesn't appear so. At this stage I have gone the route of creating my own, though I am not a PowerShell guy so I am doing it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Except creating a power-shell script, you can also install "[MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks)" nuget package to your project and use it to update the assembly information during your build.

Refer to this article for details: [VSO Build vNext – versioning assemblies with MSBuild](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2015/09/29/vso-build-vnext-versioning-assemblies-with-msbuild/)

The article shows how to update Version and FileVersion, you just need to add following section in the MSBuild script to update CopyRight and Company:

```
AssemblyCompany="xxxx"
AssemblyCopyright="xxxx"
```